# Enable monitor mode on Linux for Wireshark

Tags: linux, bash, wifi, wireshark, sniffing

I need to enable monitor mode on my Lenovo Legion computer running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS to start sniffing wifi traffic through Wireshark.
I've correctly installed Wireshark through `apt-get install` but unfortunately inside the Capture options, under the Monitor mode column, no checkbox is displayed but only a small straight line __

[image]

In addition if I run `ifconfig -a` inside the terminal, no *wlan0* interface is shown but only the *wlp3s0* interface which seems to be Ethernet (even if it is for sure the wireless interface)

[image: ifconfig -a output]

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to deal with it:

- Disable automatic reconnection (this would cause the monitor mode to be exited)
- Disconnect the PC from any wifi network
- Run these commands
- `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 down`
- `sudo iwconfig wlp3s0 mode monitor`
- `sudo ifconfig wlp3s0 up`
- `sudo wireshark`